# How to highlight the confidence region of time series prediction with a polygon

Tags: r, plot, time-series, polygon, confidence-interval

I am trying to colour a time series plot using a polygon function between the two blue lines as shown below.

My code is as follows:
[image]

Code for generating above graph is as follows:

```
set.seed(2)
Original <- ts(na.omit(rnorm(1:96,mean=20, sd=1)), frequency = 12, start=c(2008,1))
upper <- ts(na.omit(rnorm(1:96,mean=30, sd=1)), frequency = 12, start=c(2015,1),end=c(2015,12))
lower <- ts(na.omit(rnorm(1:96,mean=10, sd=1)), frequency = 12, start=c(2015,1),end=c(2015,12))
predict <- ts(na.omit(rnorm(1:96,mean=18, sd=1)), frequency = 12, start=c(2015,1),end=c(2015,12))

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(Original,type="l",col="gray", ylim=c(0,50))
lines(upper,col="blue")
lines(lower,col="blue")
lines(predict,col="red", lwd="2")
```

The polygon function I am currently using is as follows:

```
polygon(x= c(tmp,rev(tmp)),y= c(upper,rev(lower)), col="grey", border=NA)
```

The above code is good, with the exception of my X co-ordinates. I am unable to specify the X co-ordinate as it is a time series. the time series is monthly. The Blue Line starts in Jan 2015 and ends on Dec 2015.

Is there a way to specify the "X" co-ordinates for time series in a vector/matrix/ date.frame to show between Jan 2015 and Dec 2015?

My GOAL: I want to colour the area between the two blue lines and only between the two blue lines. Hence, the use of Polygon.

Comment: Hello Zheyuan Li, I intend to colour the area between the two blue lines hence, i want to use the polygon function. I have uploaded the code for your understanding/ trials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your question is really: how can I get appropriate value of variable `tmp` in my call to `polygon`.

Now, try this simply:

```
tmp <- seq(from = 2015, by = 1/12, length = 12)
polygon(x= c(tmp,rev(tmp)),y= c(upper,rev(lower)), col="grey", border=NA)
```

[image]

But you might do it yourself to make the plot look nicer, e.g. changing line colours, line width. Also, you might need to consider first drawing the polygon and then overlaying your time series plot.